# Not able to run a function of a smart contract (Create Community) from Express.js server

Tags: solidity, blockchain, ethers.js, alchemy, express

I am trying to create community from express server but getting an error. The get Community is running fine I am able to get the Community corresponding to that particular id. But when trying to send the post request from thunder-client to create community getting this error:

```
Server running on port 3000
@xxiiits
xxxxxxAP
xxxxxxxM
D:\Eth Global\ZK-Gas\server\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\lib\index.js:238
        var error = new Error(message);
                    ^

Error: bad response (status=400, headers={"date":"Wed, 14 Feb 2024 08:07:02 GMT","content-type":"application/json","content-length":"179","connection":"close","x-alchemy-trace-id":"36af6c5e74b1575cedd94e25738533ed","cf-cache-status":"DYNAMIC","set-cookie":"_cfuvid=LEXXKyRGOYMDHuy843MX.k8Z73e1oR3viXFrsHhmTDk-1707898022672-0-604800000; path=/; domain=.g.alchemy.com; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None","server":"cloudflare","cf-ray":"8553d0afeec9a929-MAA"}, body="{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"id\":47,\"error\":{\"code\":-32600,\"message\":\"Unsupported method: eth_sendTransaction. See available methods at https://docs.alchemy.com/alchemy/documentation/apis\"}}", requestBody="{\"method\":\"eth_sendTransaction\",\"params\":[{\"gas\":\"0xa89fa\",\"from\":\"0x408ec62219601eb0c77aa8cbc0aad3eefd28bebb\",\"to\":\"0x527f98da5b97269b1de0daacc49c5f7e2e69f8b7\",\"data\":\"0x75586d4a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000087878406969697473000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000878787878787841500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008787878787878784d000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\"}],\"id\":47,\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\"}", requestMethod="POST", url="https://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/lXYIHqw63t0aanO97LHphw79nvWIm2LM", code=SERVER_ERROR, version=web/5.7.1)
    at Logger.makeError (D:\Eth Global\ZK-Gas\server\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\lib\index.js:238:21)
    at Logger.throwError (D:\Eth Global\ZK-Gas\server\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\lib\index.js:247:20)
    at D:\Eth Global\ZK-Gas\server\node_modules\@ethersproject\web\lib\index.js:275:36
    at step (D:\Eth Global\ZK-Gas\server\node_modules\@ethersproject\web\lib\index.js:33:23)
    at Object.next (D:\Eth Global\ZK-Gas\server\node_modules\@ethersproject\web\lib\index.js:14:53)
    at fulfilled (D:\Eth Global\ZK-Gas\server\node_modules\@ethersproject\web\lib\index.js:5:58)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  reason: 'bad response',
  code: 'SERVER_ERROR',
  status: 400,
  headers: {
    date: 'Wed, 14 Feb 2024 08:07:02 GMT',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'content-length': '179',
    connection: 'close',
    'x-alchemy-trace-id': '36af6c5e74b1575cedd94e25738533ed',
    'cf-cache-status': 'DYNAMIC',
    'set-cookie': '_cfuvid=LEXXKyRGOYMDHuy843MX.k8Z73e1oR3viXFrsHhmTDk-1707898022672-0-604800000; path=/; domain=.g.alchemy.com; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None',
    server: 'cloudflare',
    'cf-ray': '8553d0afeec9a929-MAA'
  },
  body: '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":47,"error":{"code":-32600,"message":"Unsupported method: eth_sendTransaction. See available methods at https://docs.alchemy.com/alchemy/documentation/apis"}}',
  requestBody: '{"method":"eth_sendTransaction","params":[{"gas":"0xa89fa","from":"0x408ec62219601eb0c77aa8cbc0aad3eefd28bebb","to":"0x527f98da5b97269b1de0daacc49c5f7e2e69f8b7","data":"0x75586d4a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000087878406969697473000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000878787878787841500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008787878787878784d000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"}],"id":47,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}',
  requestMethod: 'POST',
  url: 'https://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/'
}
```

Node.js v18.18.0

Here is my Code:

```
const express = require("express");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const { exec } = require("child_process");
const ethers = require("ethers");
const { config } = require("dotenv");
const FactoryABI = require("./ABI/Factory.json");
const ZKCommunityABI = require("./ABI/ZKCommunity.json");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
config();

const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(
  `https://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/${process.env.SEPOLIA_ALCHEMY_KEY}`
);
// const signer = provider.getSigner();
const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(process.env.SEPOLIA_PRIVATE_KEY, provider);
const signer = wallet.provider.getSigner(wallet.address);
console.log(signer);
const FactoryContract = new ethers.Contract(
  FactoryABI.address,
  FactoryABI.abi,
  signer
);

const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // Use bodyParser middleware to parse JSON bodies
app.use(express.json());

function stringToBytes32(str) {
  const bytes32 = ethers.utils.formatBytes32String(str);
  return bytes32;
}

app.post("/create-community", async (req, res) => {
  // console.log(req.body);
  const body = req.body;
  const domain = body.domain;
  console.log(domain);
  const region = body.region;
  console.log(region);
  const gender = body.gender;
  console.log(gender);
  await FactoryContract.functions.createCommunity(
    "xx@iiits",
    "xxxxxxAP",
    "xxxxxxxM"
  );
  // res.send(domain);
});

console.log(FactoryContract.functions);
app.get("/get-community", async (req, res) => {
  const _id = req.query.id;
  console.log(_id);
  const community = await FactoryContract.functions.getCommunity(_id);
  // console.log(await FactoryContract.getCommunity(0));
  console.log(community);
  // res.send(community);
});

app.post("/config", (req, res) => {
  // let buffer = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(data.domain));

  try {
    const filePath = path.join(
      __dirname,
      "../",
      "noir-app",
      "circuits",
      "Prover.toml"
    );

    const domainPub = "xx@iiits";
    const regionPub = "xxxxxxAP";
    const genderPub = "xxxxxxxM";

    const domainPubBytes32 = stringToBytes32(domainPub);
    const regionPubBytes32 = stringToBytes32(regionPub);
    const genderPubBytes32 = stringToBytes32(genderPub);

    const publicInputs = [domainPubBytes32, regionPubBytes32, genderPubBytes32];

    console.log(publicInputs);

    const data = {
      domain: req.body.domain,
      region: req.body.region,
      gender: req.body.gender,
    };

    const pubData = {
      domainPub: domainPub,
      regionPub: regionPub,
      genderPub: genderPub,
    };

    let tomlString = "";

    for (const key in data) {
      if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(data, key)) {
        const arrayString = data[key].join(", ");
        tomlString += `${key} = [${arrayString}]\n`;
      }
    }
    for (const key in pubData) {
      if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(pubData, key)) {
        tomlString += `${key} = "${pubData[key]}"\n`;
      }
    }

    // console.log(tomlString);

    // const jsonDomain = JSON.stringify(tomlDomain);
    // const jsonRegion = JSON.stringify(tomlRegion);
    // const jsonGender = JSON.stringify(tomlGender);

    // const bufferDomain = Buffer.from(jsonDomain, 'utf-8');
    // const bufferRegion = Buffer.from(jsonRegion, 'utf-8');
    // const bufferGender = Buffer.from(jsonGender, 'utf-8');

    // Write the TOML string to the specified file path
    fs.writeFile(filePath, tomlString, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error("Error writing to TOML file:", err);
        res.status(500).send("Error writing to TOML file");
      }
      exec("bash ./scripts/auto_deploy.sh", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
          console.error("Error running shell commands:", error);
          res.status(500).send("Error running shell commands");
          return;
        }
        console.log("Shell commands executed successfully:", stdout);
        res
          .status(200)
          .send("TOML file written and shell commands executed successfully");

        const proof = fs.readFileSync(
          "../noir-app/circuits/proofs/noirstarter.proof"
        );
        const proofHex = "0x" + proof.toString();
        console.log(proofHex);
      });
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error parsing JSON:", error);
    res.status(400).send("Error parsing JSON");
  }
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error message

> body: '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":47,"error":{"code":-32600,"message":"Unsupported method: eth_sendTransaction. See available methods at [https://docs.alchemy.com/alchemy/documentation/apis"}}'](https://docs.alchemy.com/alchemy/documentation/apis%22%7D%7D%27),

The problem is that it isn't using the `signer` when calling `createCommunity`.